# How do I solve the LateInitializationError in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, error-handling, solution

I am having the following problem and I hope someone can help me.
I am trying to include the camera in my flutter app by using the following code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';


class Route02 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CameraState createState() => CameraState();
}

class CameraState extends State<Route02> {
  late List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  late CameraController _controller;
  bool isReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupCameras();
  }

  Future<void> setupCameras() async {
    try {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      _controller = new CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh);
      await _controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch () {
      setState(() {
        isReady = false;
      });
    }
    setState(() {
      isReady = true;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!isReady && !_controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: CameraPreview(_controller));
  }
}
```

When accessing the camera part within the app, the following error can be seen, and afterwards, the camera will start anyway.

**LateInitializationError: Field 'controller' has not been initialized.**

I have already tried to add the **whenComplete()** method and used **?** but it didn't work either.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Where is `controller` declared?  Is there some relationship between `controller` and `_controller` that you haven't provided?

Comment: @jamesdlin its the same that was just my mistake, i already fixed that but its still the same error.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you are running 'setupCameras()' which is asynchronous inside the 'initState()' method which is not. Try this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';


class Route02 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CameraState createState() => CameraState();
}

class CameraState extends State<Route02> {
  late List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  late CameraController _controller;


  Future<void> setupCameras() async {
    try {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      _controller = new CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh);
      await controller.initialize();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: setupCameras(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(_controller)
        );
      };
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but its still the same error. I have no idea why...

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem and I can't find a perfect solution.

- I don't think FutureBuilder will work in this case.  You need to handle the dispose as well.  This seems not what you can do using FutureBuilder.
- The reality is that, you may not be able to initialize CameraController successfully.  For whatever reasons the getCameras doesn't return you anything.  That means it is always possible that your CameraController can be null.  So, trying to tweak the code to force this to be non null type is not right.

I ended up just change it to nullable type and do null check whenever necessary.  IMO, dart is going to far for null safety.  It just make things more complicated.  I love the way Python handle nullable using None.

```
CameraController? _controller;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. `setupCameras()` does:

   > ```dart
   > try {
   >   // ...
   > } on CameraException catch () {
   >   setState(() {
   >     isReady = false;
   >   });
   > }
   > setState(() {
   >   isReady = true;
   > });
   > ```

   which means that if a `CameraException` is thrown, `isReady` will be set to `false` but then immediately be set to `true`.
2. The `build` function does:

   > ```dart
   > if (!isReady && !_controller.value.isInitialized) {
   >   return Container();
   > }
   > ```

   If `isReady` is false (which I assume *should* indicate that `_controller` isn't yet initialized), then you additionally check `_controller.value.isInitialized` even though `_controller` isn't initialized yet.  You probably want `||` instead `&&`.

Alternatively, consider just making `_controller` nullable instead of `late`.  If you need to check a boolean flag (`isReady`) before accessing `_controller` anyway, that's no better than making `_controller` nullable and checking `_controller != null` directly, which is more straightforward and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

The error "LateInitializationError: Field 'controller' has not been initialized" in your code is related to the _controller variable not being properly initialized. It seems that you are trying to use the _controller before it has been initialized in the initState method. You should only access _controller after it has been initialized. Here's a modified version of your code to ensure proper initialization:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera';

class Route02 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CameraState createState() => CameraState();
}

class CameraState extends State<Route02> {
  late List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  late CameraController _controller;
  bool isReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupCameras();
  }

  Future<void> setupCameras() async {
    try {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      _controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh);

      // Ensure that the widget is mounted before initializing the controller
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }

      await _controller.initialize();
      setState(() {
        isReady = true;
      });
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      setState(() {
        isReady = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose(); // Don't forget to dispose of the controller.
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!isReady || !_controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: CameraPreview(_controller),
    );
  }
}
```

> Note: Check if the widget is still mounted before initializing the
> camera controller to avoid errors. Also added a dispose method to
> properly dispose of the camera controller when the widget is disposed.